# Submit popup panel content, rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I am trying to submit values in a pop-up panel inside another panel that has a submit/action event. But before opening pop-up panel I need to invoke a function on my managed bean that create a new entity object. The outer panel has the only *h:form*, since you can't nest them. I have wrapped the pop-up panel in a *a4j:region* to submit only this part when the use submits the values inside the pop-up panel. This works, but not the execution of the preparing function that need to be invoked when the pop-up panel executes. I have tried *a4j:commandLink* but that component don't work together with the **rich:popupPanel** (strange since both of them are Richfaces components?!). So I have to relay on the **h:commandLink** and use ajax.

How can I invoke a function on my managed bean when the link to open/render the pop-up panel fires?

*(What is the correct pattern for this?)*

PS. The initial question has changed, but not the problem concerning submitting values in a pop-up panel.

Part of the xhtml file:

```
<h.form>
...
<a4j:region>
      <rich:popupPanel id="popup_sys_user_req" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Request New Sector/Category" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="controls">
                            <h:outputLink value="#"
                                          onclick="#{rich:component('popup_sys_user_req')}.hide(); return false;">
                                X
                            </h:outputLink>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Request New:" />
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="sys_req_type" value="#{userController.selectedSysUserRequest.sysrequesttype}" required="true" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{userController.getSysRequestTypeItems('SECTOR_CATEGORY')}">
                                </f:selectItems>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                            <h:inputTextarea id="user_req_desc" value="#{userController.selectedSysUserRequest.description(desc)}" required="true" requiredMessage="Decription is missing" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <a4j:commandButton action="#{userController.CreateSysUserRequest()}" value="Send Request" execute="sys_user_req_form" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup_sys_user_req')}.hide(); return false;"/>
                    </rich:popupPanel>
                </a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

The commandLink (**re-edit**)

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{userController.prepareCreateSysRequest}" value="Request New Sector/Category">    
    <f:ajax  execute="popup_sys_user_req @this" render="popup_sys_user_req">
        <rich:componentControl id="popup_ctr" event="click" target="popup_sys_user_req" operation="show"/>
    </f:ajax>                                
</h:commandLink>
----------------------------
//Managed Bean:
public void prepareCreateSysRequest(ActionEvent event ) {
    selectedSysUserRequest = new Sysuserrequest();
    JsfUtil.log("Prepare Create System User Request");
}
```

[This post continues the dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062931/how-to-submit-values-in-a-pop-up-panel) about the pop-up panel.
Greetings Chris.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to submit all form elements inside popupPanel but not outside the panel when you invoke someAction1? I can think of two ways to do this:
1. a4jcommandButton has a limitToList attribute, you can list which components you want to be updated on the server
2. create your popupPanel outside of the first form and then use its own form:

```
<h:form>
...
<a4j:commandButton action="someAction2"...
</h:form>

<rich:popupPanel>
<h:form>
...
<a4j:commandButton action="someAction1"...
</h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

**Update**
If you are using RichFaces 4 you can replace the limitToList attribute with limitRender

Comment: I using richfaces 4 and there is no limitToList for the commandbutton. Think that's why there is region, but not sure. Will try the second suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: A follow up question, I try to restrict the processing by using execute=@form. The second form on the page, but it seams that it tries to submit the other one as well. Is rich:region the way to go?

Comment: When I move the pop-up panel into its own form, the header of the pop-up panel disappear. JSF is not for the weak hearted I guess ?!

Comment: The only problem left is to invoke a prepareCreate() from the action. The function I refer to in the action="" will not execute. I tried the a4j:commandLink but then the pop-up panel doesn't show. What to do ?

Comment: When you said you moved the popupPanel in its own form could you post your code? Could you try adding the form inside the popupPanel and not the popupPanel inside the form? Do you have a <f:facet name="header"> defined?

Comment: have a look at this link, someone posted an example of how theirs works: http://community.jboss.org/message/565975#565975. They mention a bug with a4j:commandButton and popupPanel as well as work around

Comment: Also another interesting link related to using a form outside the popupPanel: http://community.jboss.org/message/601103#601103. Basically says: "you have to use domElementAttachment set to form or parent in order the submissions from component to work properly."

Comment: Still wrestling with the problem. The links put me on a new path, but the problem with invoking bean function when opening the pop-up panel is still an issue.

Comment: This question turned into another problem concerning submiting the values inside the pop-up panel. Instead of the form/region problem that I had initially. Pleas follow this link for the other question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062931/how-to-submit-values-in-a-pop-up-panel

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the popup isn't a child of the form in jsf, you only need to use the **domElementAttachment** attribute to change that. So your code would look like this:

```
    <h.form>
...
<a4j:region>
      <rich:popupPanel id="popup_sys_user_req" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false" domElementAttachment="form">
      <f:facet name="header">
...
```