# How to submit values in a pop-up panel?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, richfaces

I have bean struggling to understand how to use the *rich:popupPanel* component in the right way. There are (at least not that I could find) few post about how to use the *rich:popupPanel* and how to submit values from it.

To make matter worse the panel seams to add (when checking the html) a hard coded "_content" to its component id name (to the div generated). I have tried to use *aj4:region* tag to partial render the complete form. But that didn't seamed to work, cause nothing where posted to managed bean. So now I have one option left, where the panel has its own form, outside the main one on the page.

I can see that the evaluation of the form (popup) values is happening, but not the execution of the bean function that persist the values (I see the POST request of the command button). The only reason I can think of at the moment, is that the pop-up panel use another bean to persist the values that the main form on the page (both of them are session scoped).
I am thinking of omit the pop-up panel all together, since it seams so hard to make this work. Maybe its a well know secret, since it so few post about it. It behaves the same if if use *componentController* or only a *a4j:commanLink*.

How is it possible to submit values from a *rich:popupPanel* and invoke a backing bean function to persist the pop-up form values ?

Appreciate if someone can shed some light on this, greetings Chris.

I use Richfaces 4.0-final on Glassfish 3.1

```
<h:form id="main_form">
<!-- Command for popup -->
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{userController.prepareCreateSysRequest}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup_sys_user_req_form:popup_sys_user_req')}.show(); return false;" 
                                     execute="@this" value="Request New Sector/Category" />

    ...
<a4j:commandButton action="#{projectController.Create}" ...>
</h:form>

<h:form id="popup_sys_user_req_form">
    <rich:popupPanel id="popup_sys_user_req" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="New Project Request" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink value="#"
                          onclick="#{rich:component('popup_sys_user_req')}.hide(); return false;">
                X
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Request New:" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="sys_req_type" value="#{userController.selectedSysRequestType}" required="true" requiredMessage="Request Type is required" title="Request Type">
                <f:selectItems value="#{userController.getSysRequestTypeItems()}">
                </f:selectItems>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputLabel value="Description:" />
            <h:inputTextarea id="user_req_desc" value="#{userController.selectedSysUserRequest.description}" required="true" requiredMessage="Decription is missing" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{userController.CreateSysUserRequest}" onclick="#{rich:component('popup_sys_user_req')}.hide(); return false;" execute="@form" render="popup_sys_user_req_form" value="Send Request" />
    </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 5):

For what I have done I used to have the issue to got to submit twice only the first time.

To fix it the form got to be outside the popupPane. And also that the popupPanel should have the attibute domElementAttachment="form".

Example.

```
        <h:form>
            <rich:popupPanel id="shipmentItemUpdateDialog" 
                             autosized="true"
                             domElementAttachment="form">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemDetailsHeader}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <h:commandLink>
                        <h:graphicImage value="/core/images/modal/close.png"/>
                        <rich:componentControl target="shipmentItemUpdateDialog" operation="hide" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText for="shipmentItemName"
                              value="#{coreBundle.requiredChar} #{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemName}"
                              />
                <h:inputText id="shipmentItemName" 
                             disabled ="false"
                             required ="true"
                             value="#{shipmentItemController.shipmentItemUI.value.name}" 
                             label="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemName}"
                             size="40" >
                </h:inputText>  

                <h:outputText for="shipmentItemCode"
                              value="#{coreBundle.requiredChar} #{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemCode}"
                              />
                <h:inputText id="shipmentItemCode" 
                             disabled ="false"
                             required ="true"
                             value="#{shipmentItemController.shipmentItemUI.value.code}" 
                             label="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemCode}"
                             size="40" >
                </h:inputText>         

                <h:outputText value="#{coreBundle.requiredChar} #{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemAmount}"
                              />
                <h:inputText id="shipmentItemAmount" 
                             disabled ="false"
                             required ="true"
                             value="#{shipmentItemController.shipmentItemUI.value.amount}" 
                             label="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemAmount}"
                             size="4" >
                    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1"/>
                </h:inputText>      


                <h:outputText value="#{coreBundle.requiredChar} #{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemNeedsCooling}"
                              />
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="shipmentItemNeedsCooling" 
                                         disabled ="false"
                                         required ="true"
                                         value="#{shipmentItemController.shipmentItemUI.value.needsCooling}" 
                                         label="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemNeedsCooling}"
                                         />                    

                <h:outputText for="shipmentItemDetails"
                              value="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemDetails}"
                              />
                <h:inputTextarea id="shipmentItemDetails" 
                                 disabled ="false"
                                 required ="true"
                                 value="#{shipmentItemController.shipmentItemUI.value.details}" 
                                 label="#{shipmentBundle.shipmentItemDetails}"
                                 cols="38" 
                                 rows="5" 
                                 /> 
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1" dir="LTR">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" dir="LTR">
                    <a4j:commandButton value="#{coreBundle.acceptButton}" 
                                       action="#{shipmentItemController.onUpdate()}"
                                       render="shipmentItemsTable">
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                    <h:commandLink value="#{coreBundle.closeLink}" 
                                   immediate="true">
                        <rich:componentControl target="shipmentItemUpdateDialog" operation="hide" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText value="#{coreBundle.requiredText}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            </rich:popupPanel>              
        </h:form>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: your solution solved my problem, but can you please explain me what is the use of this attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it right.. think of the pop-up as a regular page. To submit and close the pop-up, do something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Save" onclick="#{rich:component('panelId}.hide();" render="..."/>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: oncomplete should also work. Can you set the value when not using a pop-up panel?

Comment: Found this thread, but not a clear solution. http://community.jboss.org/thread/165382

Comment: The only problem (I hope) I still have left is that the values is not being set in the backing bean. The value is not native, it's a entity class. Which get set when the *a4j:commandLink* invoke the **prepare** function. If it's a native or POJO wouldn't be any different ?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't matter. I guess also make sure that the same objects exists when you do a submit from regular page and when you do a submit from a pop-up.